# AFNetworking 3.0 download *.m4r file

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2, afnetworking-3

I have an old project and try to update it from AFNetworking 2.* to AFNetworking 3.0. Everything seems to work fine, except downloading m4r files. Old code used something like this:

```
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLString]];
[request setValue:@"gzip" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];
AFHTTPRequestOperation* requestOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
requestOperation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
requestOperation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:outPath append:NO];
[requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation* operation, id responseObject) {
            //
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation* operation, NSError* error) {
    //
}];
[requestOperation setDownloadProgressBlock:downloadProgressBlock];
[requestOperation start];
```

I'm not sure, how to move logic with output stream logic to AFNetwroking 3.0, so for now I left it and rewrote old code with:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager* manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[manager.responseSerializer setAcceptableContentTypes: [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObjectsFromArray: @[@"video/mp4", @"audio/mpeg"]]];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue: @"gzip" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Accept-Encoding"];
[manager GET: URLString parameters: nil progress: downloadProgressBlock success: ^ (NSURLSessionTask* task, id responseObject) {
        //
    }           failure: ^ (NSURLSessionTask* operation, NSError* error) {
        //
}];
```

The line with setting acceptableContentTypes is added, because without it I was receiving an error with description:

> "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: video/mp4"

Now, after fixing this error, I'm getting

> "Unable to convert data to a string using the detected encoding. The
>   data may be corrupt."

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix it with download task. My code looks like this:

```
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLString]];
[request setValue:@"gzip" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];

AFHTTPSessionManager* manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
NSURLSessionDownloadTask* downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest: request progress: downloadProgressBlock destination: ^ NSURL*(NSURL* targetPath, NSURLResponse* response) {
    return [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: outPath];
}                                                       completionHandler: ^ (NSURLResponse* response, NSURL* filePath, NSError* error) {
    completion(error == nil, error);
}];
[downloadTask resume];
```